# How can I get a single object's audio response from a pair of colliding audio?

Tags: fft, signal-analysis, impulse-response

## Problem and backgroud

Two objects $A$ and $B$ are colliding and produce audio response $x_{AB}(t) = x_A(t) + x_B(t)$, where $x_A(t)$ and $x_B(t)$ are audio produce by these two objects individually.

In another word, I just apply impulse on $A$ and $B$ and get their response.

My project is only interested in the vibration of $x_A(t)$ , **how can I remove the effect of $x_B(t)$?**  Acutally $B$ is an impact hammer which can be made of wood or steel.

I'm really sorry, but I have very few knowledge on DSP and complex analysis. Thanks for any help.

## My own method

I come up with a "werid" method based on FFT. But I cannot make it work.

My idea is:

1. Introduce the third object $C$.
2. Then make $A, B, C$ collides with each other, it will produce:
   $$
       x_{AB} = x_A + x_B\\
       x_{BC} = x_B + x_C\\
       x_{AC} = x_A + x_C\\
      $$
3. After the FFT, they became:
   $$
       X_{AB}(\omega) = X_A(\omega) + X_B(\omega) \\
       X_{BC}(\omega) = X_B(\omega) + X_C(\omega) \\
       X_{AC}(\omega) = X_A(\omega) + X_C(\omega) \\
      $$
4. Then, I can solve the equation and get $X_A, X_B, X_C$.

It doesn't work at all. How to solve this problem? How to get the only signal of object $A$? Why my method doesn't work.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Can you mount an accelerometer on object A in order to isolate its vibration from object B? Or use some optical interferometry to accomplish the same?

Comment: Do you have any motivation or reference for your model of the combined response? It does not seem very plausible to me.